# SwiftUI's new NavigationStack does not navigate to next screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to integrate `NavigationStack` in my `SwiftUI` app, I have three views `CealUIApp`, `OnBoardingView` and `UserTypeView`. I just want to navigate from `OnBoardingView` to `UserTypeView` when user presses a button in `OnBoardingView`

Below is my code for `CealUIApp`

```
@main
struct CealUIApp: App {
    
    @State private var path = [String]()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path){
                OnBoardingView(path: $path)
            }.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
                UserTypeView()
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in `OnBoardingView`, the button code is as follows

```
Button {
                    path.append("UserTypeView")
                } label: {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
```

As soon as I press the button I am not navigated to `UserTypeView`, instead I just see a white screen with a warning icon at the centre

[image]

Comment: do you use `@Binding var path: [String]` in your `OnBoardingView`?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I just want to navigate from OnBoardingView to UserTypeView when user presses a button in OnBoardingView`,
then try this approach, where `.navigationDestination(...)` is moved to the `OnBoardingView`,
as shown in this example code:

```
@main
struct CealUIApp: App {
    
    @State var path = [String]()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                OnBoardingView(path: $path)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OnBoardingView: View {
    @Binding var path: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            path.append("UserTypeView")
        } label: {
            Text("go to UserTypeView")
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
            UserTypeView()
        }
    }
}

struct UserTypeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("UserTypeView")
    }
}
```